# When is forEach or map counting?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a question about the `_.map` loop: when exactly is this loop counting?

I have a JavaScript object I want to iterate:

```
var data = {
    "$$state": {
        "status": 1,
        "value": [{"anything": 002}]
    },
    "restangular": true
}
```

In this case, it would just take the state. Why is it taking the state one and some other not?

When I get into the state and I want to iterate this one via:

```
var anything = _.map(cockpitdata, function(x){counter++; return x; });
```

It won't count anything, although it's the same structure as above.

Comment: I've edited the question to be a bit clearer, but I still don't completely understand the question: what do you *expect* to happen?

Comment: _n this case, it would just take the state. Why is it taking the state one and some other not?_ Nope -> http://jsfiddle.net/fwndqxnm/

Comment: If you only want to count the keys just use `Object.keys(data).length`

Comment: What's `cockpitdata`? Where is  `counter` initialised?

Comment: What do you mean by "*Why is it taking the state one and some other not?*"

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is unclear.

map is a bad choice for counting. It seems like you are trying to count properties of cockpitdata.

You can try using

```
_.keys(cockpitdata).length
```